# Release version of UWP app does not contain assets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, assets, release

the application i am working on runs absolutely fine in Debug mode in Visual Studio. But as soon as i tried to open the Release version it crashes at the point where it needs resources (the icon pictures that are generated in VS are fine but everything else). For example:
At one point i need to read in from an .csv document. Through painstakingly commenting out the parts where i do this i have found out that it crashes because it does not find the assets.

I have my Assets in the \APPNAME\APPNAME\Assets, \APPNAME\APPNAME\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Assets, \APPNAME\APPNAME\bin\x86\Release\AppX\Assets

And when i say Release version i mean the proper release thingy. Because it runs just fine in release mode when it is run via Visual Studio.

I get my assets always with this code :

```
string path = "\\Assets\\DOCUMENTNAME.FILETYPE";

string localPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + path;

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(localPath);
```

is that wrong? Or is ther something within Visual Studio that i need to configure so that it gets the assets into the release version?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Could you tell me if you have imported your files into Assets(that is, find your files under the Assets node of the Solution Explorer)?

Comment: Yes i did, it turns out that for some reasons they got deleted upon build. It fixed itself somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i had not copied the assets to all locations needed.